# Rotating a line around a point in OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, trigonometry

I am trying to rotate a line around a point which is not (0,0).

For this program, I am trying not to use `glRotatef()` and trying to use trigonometry. However the length of the line will always change.

Any suggestions?

This is my code:

```
public class World implements GLEventListener, KeyListener
{
    double xOne = 0.1;
    double yOne = 0.1;
    double xTwo = 0;
    double yTwo = 0.01;

    double i = 220.987;

    public World()
    {

    }

    public void init(GLAutoDrawable gld)
    {
        Animator theAnimator = new Animator(gld);
        theAnimator.start();
    }

    public void display(GLAutoDrawable gld)
    {
       GL gl = gld.getGL();
       gl.glEnable(gl.GL_BLEND);
       gl.glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

       gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

       gl.glBegin(gl.GL_LINES);
        gl.glColor3d(1,0,0);
        gl.glVertex2d(xOne ,yOne);
        gl.glColor3d(0,0,1);
        gl.glVertex2d(xTwo, yTwo);
       gl.glEnd();

       gl.glFlush();
       //UPDATE
    }

    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable gLAutoDrawable, int _int, int _int2, int _int3, int _int4) 
    {

    }

    public void displayChanged(GLAutoDrawable gLAutoDrawable, boolean _boolean, boolean _boolean2)
    {

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke)
    {

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke)
    {
        if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
        {
            xTwo = (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i))+xOne);
            yTwo = (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i))+yOne);
            i++;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke)
    {

    }
}
```

By the way, `(xOne, yOne)` is the stationary point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would do this by translating to (0,0), rotating around (0,0), and translating back. So it is a 3-step process:

1. Subtract (xOne,yOne) from your points.
2. Do a rotation around (0,0) using trigonometry. (I am assuming you already know how to do this, or you can look it up.)
3. Add (xOne,yOne) back to your points again.

In your case, I think your code is almost correct already. What you are missing is a multiplication by the length of the line. Use the distance formula to find the distance between (xOne,yOne) and (xTwo,yTwo), and multiply that distance by the sine and cosine values, before adding xOne and yOne.

Comment: Sorry i did not get that

Comment: @kimchiboy03 That's not very informative. If you want to get help, tell us what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: @kimchiboy03 I answered your question, but looking back it sounds like you would have preferred that I fix your code. I've amended my answer to give you a suggestion for that, too.

Comment: @JamesVanderhyde Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Understanding transformation is a requirement to working effectively in OpenGL.

Transformations deal with how one system can be represented in two different manners.  So a point that's at (3,4) can be transformed into a point that's at (0,0) in an "alternate universe" where the origin is at (3,4).

Rotating around a point is pretty easy, it's basically the formula

```
(x', y') = (x-a, y-a) (where x's is the "new x" and x is the "old" x)
```

Likewise, this can be reversed really easily

```
(x, y) = (x'+a, y'+a)
```

Rotation transformations look like

```
(x', y') = ((x*cos(a) + y*sin(a)), (-x*sin(a)+y*cos(a)))
```

which gives you a new x' and y' for a point rotated by a radians around the origin.

So, to rotate in OpenGL, you first transform all the points to have a new origin, the origin of rotation.  Then you rotate around that origin.  Then you transform all the points away from the new origin back to the old origin.

It's just like James said above, I'm just using more words.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion